# How do I send myself an email using Python?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I know this has been answered before, but recently gmail updated the ["Less secure apps" ToS or something.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=1#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-off-for-your-account) So with this update, is there a way to do this? (Sorry for short explanation + old duplicates)

Tried [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-gmail-account-using-python/) and when trying to connect to my google acc, less secure apps option disabled

UPDATE: I'll be using chrome notifications, which is useful for what I'm doing. Thanks for trying to help! :D

Comment: Read the page you linked to in your question. *"If "Less secure app access" is turned off for your account, you can [turn it back on](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps). We recommend switching to [more secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=1#more-secure-apps-how) instead."*

Comment: Would you please edit your question and include your code so that i can see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo yea i did, app passwords just failed on the code (will provide code when i get home. thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

You can or should be able to use the same code that you are using now.  The easest solution would be to enable 2fa on your google account and create an apps password.  [Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Once you have created the apps password you can use that in place of your standard gmail password in your code.

If that doesn't work you can switch to using Xoauth2 and authorize a user and send an access token instead.  This method would probably require changes you your existing code.